# Installer created with Install4J trying to write to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Tags: install4j

When installing on Windows 7 as a non-admin we are seeing this error:

```
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.registry.SetRegistryValueAction: could not create key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT .djk

[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.desktop.CreateFileAssociationAction: [ID djk association] error setting internal name
```

I have gone through the install4J wizard and changed settings such that the installer does not require admin privs. This works, but the installer still attempts to write to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT - an area of the registry which the user does not have write access.

What logic tells Install4J installers to write to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT?

Can I configure my installer such that it writes file associations to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes and never to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT?

Comment: Does this concern the "Create file association action"? As of 6.1, install4j does not support creating per-user file associations.

Comment: Yes, this happens during the "Create file association action"

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use that action without admin privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Ingo Kegel, the "Create file association action" (which I was using) As of 6.1, install4j does not support creating per-user file associations. This action requires admin rights.